# Proving a property of cubic root of unity.

Tags: complex-numbers

Can anyone help on proving below expression?

For $w$(complex cubic root of unity), 
$1+w^r+w^2 r = 0$ for any positive integer $r$, which is not a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$(X-1)(1+X+X^2) = X^3-1$ for any $X$; and $0 = (w^{3})^{r} - 1 = (w^r)^3-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $w^r \neq 1$ since $r$ is not a multiple of $3$, and so $w^r - 1 \neq 0 \Rightarrow (w^r-1)(1+w^r+w^{2r})=(w^r)^3 - 1 = (w^3)^r - 1 = 1^r-1 = 1 - 1 = 0\Rightarrow 1+w^r+w^{2r} = 0$